# How to store an English dictionary?

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary, vector

I am writing a C++ program that reads in an English dictionary (asc. order) and than does further processing.

In the first step, I decided to read all the content to a 2D-array.

```
string dictionary[x][y];
```

where `x` is only of size 26, representing A-Z, and `y` is to save the word that relative the `x` variable.

But I cannot predict the size of `y` and it is variable, so I don't know how this could be done.

Secondly, I heard that of a container called `vector`.  How can I use `vector` to do the above design? For example, using a 2D Vector, and using the first dimension to carry the first letter and the second to carry the word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your compiler support some c++11 features

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{       
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > dictionary(26);
    //'a' part
    dictionary[0].push_back("alien");
    dictionary[0].push_back("amend");
    dictionary[0].push_back("apple");

    //.......
    //'z' part
    dictionary[25].push_back("zero");
    dictionary[25].push_back("zoo");

    //sort all of the words after insert
    for(auto &strs : dictionary){
        std::sort(std::begin(strs), std::end(strs));
    }

    //find the specific words of 'a'
    auto const it = std::equal_range(std::begin(dictionary[0]), std::end(dictionary[0]), "apple");
    if(it.first != it.second){
        std::cout<<*(it.first)<<std::endl;
    }else{
        std::cout<<"The word do not exist"<<std::endl;
    }           

    return 0;
}
```

if not, then the codes would become a little bit tedious

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{       
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > dictionary(26);
    //'a' part
    dictionary[0].push_back("alien");
    dictionary[0].push_back("amend");
    dictionary[0].push_back("apple");

    //.......
    //'z' part
    dictionary[25].push_back("zero");
    dictionary[25].push_back("zoo");            

    //you could use std::for_each if you like, I choose for loop because I
    //don't like to write so many trivial functor
    typedef std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >::size_type size_type;
    size_type const size = dictionary.size();
    for(size_type i = 0; i != size; ++i){
       std::sort(dictionary[i].begin(), dictionary[i].end());
    }

    //find the specific words of 'a'
    typedef std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator StrIter;
    std::pair<StrIter, StrIter> it = std::equal_range(dictionary[0].begin(), dictionary[0].end(), "apple");
    if(it.first != it.second){
        std::cout<<*(it.first)<<std::endl;
    }else{
        std::cout<<"The word do not exist"<<std::endl;
    }    

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `multimap` with `char` and `string`.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

multimap<char,string> dictionary;

void printLetter(char ch)
{
    for (auto it=dictionary.equal_range(ch).first; it!=dictionary.equal_range(ch).second; ++it)
    {
        cout << it->second << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    fstream file;
    file.open("file.txt");
    //Read the data from the file
    while(!file.eof())
    {
        string temp;
        file >> temp;
        dictionary.insert(pair<char,string>(temp[0],temp));
    }

    file.close();
    //Print all
    for(auto i: dictionary)
    {
        cout << i.first << ":" << i.second << endl;
    }
    //Print words starting with specific letter
    printLetter('A');

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer your question you would do:

```
std::vector<string> dictionary[26];
```

`dictionary[4]` is now a `vector`(like a variable length array) of `strings`

But there are better ways to store a sorted dictionary. If you are never adding words you can just put the whole thing into a `std::vector<std::string>` and sort it once using `std::sort(dictionary.begin(), dictionary.end())`. Or if you need to add/remove words and keep a sorted list all the time you could use a `std::set<std::string>` which is always sorted (when you insert a word it will put it in the proper place)

Answer (score 1):

You should use Trie Data Structure to store dictionary.
[here is a C implementation of Trie](http://simplestcodings.blogspot.in/2012/11/trie-implementation-in-c.html). you can easily work out for C++

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of array of vectors: `std::vector<string> dictionary[26]`. The idea behind this would be the same as your first one (apart from adding words to the rows with `std::vector::push_back()` method ;) )

Answer (score 0):

you can keep the dictionary in

```
 std::vector<std::pair< string,std::vector<string> > >
```

structure so that each vector element will include a character and word list in vectors.